# What text editors support vertical rulers?

Tags: html, text-editor, rulers

I'm looking for a feature somewhat like the vertical red 80 columns marker in NetBeans but one that's easier to use.  I'd like it to function more like the tabs in MS Word except that the horizontal line is displayed on the entire file.  I looked on the [Comparison of Text Editors over at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) and I didn't find that "vertical ruler" was one of their features.

It would be used to line up html tags in a massive file that I did not create, but have to maintain.

Comment: Please don't vote to close. This question clearly relates to programming and meets all the criteria in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Alternative idea: Did you consider just running the HTML through some reformatter/prettyprinter?  Then indentation will be corrected automatically, and you can repeat as often as needed after editing.

Comment: @sleske If the HTML was good enough to run through a parser/pretty printer I wouldn't be asking this question.  8-layer deep table-based layout.  

It's not that it's not indented it that the matching tag might be 20 screens full down the file.

I didn't write it but I need to maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ has this feature.

At http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/87027?l=1 is a way to get a similar behavior in vim.

Answer (score 3):

The [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) has the option to set two vertical column markers. The first is the *line wrap column* and the second is the *left margin column* and the settings for both of these markers are found in the *document type*.

These markers are drawn as a solid vertical line one pixel in width.

Answer (score 1):

You can do column guides in Visual Studio: [blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2004/05/05/257953.aspx) (registry entry required though).

Comment: Well that's decent at least...:\

Comment: Seems as though I could do better...maybe...I don't really want to restart vs everytime I add a new guide...